# Is central charge related to symmetry?

Tags: symmetry, entropy, quantum-entanglement, conformal-field-theory, critical-phenomena

I am currently reading the paper "Theory of finite-entanglement scaling at one-dimensional quantum critical points" by Pollmann et. al. and I am trying to understand the central charge in terms of symmetry and universality. For instance, in the very beginning of the paper the authors mention that

> > The entanglement entropy is a measure of the quantum-mechanical nature of correlations and in many cases is also universal.

When I think of universality I always think of symmetry. For instance, when we consider universal classes, we see that systems with various microscopic details are placed into the same universal class because they have the same critical exponents and the same scaling behaviors, all of which arise from the Hamiltonians having the same symmetry.

So when I saw the above sentence from the paper, I was thinking that oftentimes the entanglement entropy depends on the symmetries of the system.

This brings me to figure 1 in this paper, which is shown below. The y-axis is the entanglement entropy of simulated quantum critical systems and the x-axis is the natural logarithm of the bond dimension.

[image]

The equation satisfied by these systems in the limit of large $\chi$ is

$$
S = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{12}{c} + 1}}\ln \chi
$$

where c is the central charge.

Hence in the limit of large $\chi$, we see that the simulated entanglement entropies have a slope that depends on the central charge of the system. Thinking of the sentence

> > The entanglement entropy is a measure of the quantum-mechanical nature of correlations and in many cases is also universal

**is the central charge dependent on the symmetries of the system?**

Comment: The central charge is determined by the universality class of the critical system, or basically what kind of 1+1d conformal field theory (CFT) it is at low energy. The latter has a lot of symmetries, often more than those of the microscopic model.

Comment: @MengCheng Thank you so much!!